# Magento 1.9.1 display selected swatche in cart

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I'm running attributes configurables swatches on Magento CE 1.9.1.1 and are working well on the product view but now I've to display which swatched was selected in the cart resume, so for example:

An user selects the swatch with the color red in the product X so in the shopping cart resume I've to display something like this

Product X -- color: (here I've to display the swatch red) --- Price: $100

Comment: I take it that this feature is not using the standard Configurable Product? Magento automatically displays selected options for those, so you might want to take a look at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` where it does `$this->getOptionList()`.

Comment: activate template hints and try some debug

Comment: Right now I'm able to retreive the selected properties of a configurable product in the shopping cart but I don't want to retrieve the text about which property the user selected, I want to retreive the swatch of that property so for example, if an user selects the color "red" I want to display the swatch in red color instead the label "Color: Red"

Comment: @PabloGaviria any solutions ?